# In Rails, how to update record from show view (and not edit)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, checkbox, get

After many googling, I can't find something relevant...
I have a student model with view (edit, index, show). *Edit* view are only viewed by student and *index* and *show* views are viewed by admin staff.
I would the admin staff could check a checkbox on the *show* view to "sign" or say "done" at this record.
If the check box is checked, i would a "sign information" like time.now and current_user name.
I should save this in the student record. How to do that because show is a "get" form and I would a "post" action...

Could you help me ?

Many thanks in advance

Nicolas

Comment: You can have a form on the Show page. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for your, it was the right way !!!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the page is not relevant, you can put a form or "action" link any page. To just show something to administrators, you could create a method `admin_user` in a helper file which checks if the current user is an admin, and then put the following code in your view:

```
<% if admin_user? %>
  <%= link_to "Check", sign_path %>
<% end %>
```

You could then create a route and controller action "Sign" which will mark a specific record as signed. You could also use a form in the above code.